# angular js - condition in select "comprehension expression"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i've got an angular app that maps one set of objects to another set of objects via two select elements.
when a mapping is made, the mapped objects' "mapped" property gets set to true.

```
<select ng-model='sourceToMap' required='true' ng-options='code.code for code in sourceCodes'>
<select ng-model='targetToMap' required='true' ng-options='code.code for code in targetCodes'></select>
```

i'd like my select to show all the items in sourceCodes/targetCodes whose mapped property is false.  something like...

```
ng-options="code.code for code in sourceCodes where code.mapped = false"
```

if possible, i'd like to avoid having a mappedItems / unmappedItems collection cause that seems really gross

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a filter, like this:

```
ng-options="code.code for code in sourceCodes | filter:{mapped: false}"
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/T97DN/